# How to implement data from input to array of objects in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-context

I have two components, first one is used for getting data from form, second one is used for saving collected data.
There is `rideData` object in `AddRideForm.js` where I store data from input. I want to foreward this object to `rides-context` file and insert it here `const [rides, setRides] = useState`. Can you please tell me why there is no collected data in useState() mentioned above after I print it in console ?

AddRideForm.js

```
const AddRideForm2 = () => {
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState({
    name: "",
    hour: "",
  });

const ctx = useContext(RidesContext);

  const nameHandler = (e) => {
    setUserInput((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, name: e.target.value };
    });
  };

const hourHandler = (e) => {
    setUserInput((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, hour: e.target.value };
    });
  };

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const rideData = {
      name: userInput.name,
      hour: userInput.hour,
    };

    ctx.onAdd(rideData);
    console.log(userInput);
    console.log(ctx.ridesList);
    console.log(ctx.onAdd);
  };

 return (
    <RidesContextProvider>
      <form className={classes.addRideFormContainer} onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Input
          className={classes.addRideFormInput}
          value={userInput.name}
          onChange={nameHandler}
        ></Input>
        <Input
          className={classes.addRideFormInput}
          value={userInput.hour}
          onChange={hourHandler}
        ></Input>
        <button className={classes.addRideFormButton}>Dodaj</button>
      </form>
    </RidesContextProvider>
  );
};

export default AddRideForm2;
```

rides-context.js

```
const RidesContext = React.createContext({
  ridesList: {},
  onAdd: (data) => {},
  onDelete: () => {},
});

export const RidesContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [rides, setRides] = useState([
    {
      hour: "12:00",
      name: "Jan",
    },
    {
      hour: "12:00",
      name: "Bartek ",
    },
    {
      hour: "12:00",
      name: "Kamil",
    },
  ]);

  const addRideHandler = (data) => {
    setRides(data);
  };

  return (
    <RidesContext.Provider
      value={{
        ridesList: rides,
        onAdd: addRideHandler,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </RidesContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default RidesContext;
```

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify what is happening (or what is not happening) that you want to change.

Comment: Whats the actual problem

Comment: I've just clarified it

Comment: OK, so the console.logs in AddRideForm.js that you've shown are reporting what you expect.  You should add logging to `addRideHandler` to show that `data` is what you expect.  For one thing, I see that `rides` is an array, but you are passing an object instead of an array of objects.